# How to make RStudio server recognize location of R version

Tags: r, configuration, rstudio-server

I'm using the free version of [Rstudio Server](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download-server/).
And I have a new R version stored under this directory:

```
/home/ubuntu/.R-4.1.0/bin/R
```

I want my RStudio to recognize R from that directory.
So I made changes in `/etc/rstudio/rserver.conf` by adding this line to that file:

```
rsession-which-r=/home/ubuntu/.R-4.1.0/bin/R
```

Then I restart the server:

```
sudo rstudio-server restart
```

However when I reload my R-studio server, it said the site can't be reached.
How can I resolve the issue?

[image]

Note that, it'll work with this line which is the default R location:

```
rsession-which-r=/usr/bin/R
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the R interpreter you want to use to the $PATH, possibly only for the duration of a caller script.  For example when I do (in a standard Ubuntu shell in Terminal)

```
PATH="/usr/local/lib/R-devel/bin:$PATH" rstudio
```

then RStudio (desktop) starts with my local, usually off-path, version of R-devel instead of my default (Ubuntu) R 4.1.0.

So you would do

```
PATH="/home/ubuntu/.R-4.1.0/bin/:$PATH" rstudio-server
```

to start RStudio server.  You can layer this and make the above a script in `/usr/local/sbin` (say) to be found before your actual rstudio server instance.

The easier solution, of course, may be to just install R 4.1.0 for Ubuntu from CRAN as described in [the standard README](http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/).